# Preparing two side page layout

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, layout, textwidth, textheight

My university provided me with a LaTeX template to prepare my thesis but they didn't update the class file although they have changed the rules. In the image, you will see the current rules. Also, the following code part of the class file is the relevant part for it. I tried everything I know but I failed. Can anyone please update it for me?
[image]

Rules in the image file: top, bottom, outer sides: 2.5 cm spaces, inner sides: 4 cm spaces

Besides the image file, they also said that:

> Page numbers must be 1.5 cm above the bottom of the page, in the
> direction of the reading.

```
\AtBeginDocument{
    \setlength{\voffset}{-4mm}
    \setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{14.6mm}
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{1mm}     %% 1 in(25.4 mm) + 15.6mm = 40 mm
    \setlength{\topmargin}{3mm}       
    \setlength{\headheight}{0.0mm}         
    \setlength{\headsep}{0.0mm}             
    \setlength{\textheight}{238mm}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{145mm}           
    \setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm}
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{0mm}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{1.25em}
    \setlength{\leftmarginii}{2.2em}
    \setlength{\leftmarginiii}{2.2em}
    \setlength{\leftmarginiv}{2.2em}
    \setlength{\leftmarginv}{2.2em}
    \setlength{\leftmarginvi}{2.2em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}
    \setlength{\footskip}{15mm} 
    \setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}             
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \markright{}
    \onecolumn
    \raggedbottom
    \normalsize
    \normalfont
    \oneandonehalf
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}            
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use package [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set the margins. It is quite easy to use (see the manual). But because the margins in the code above are set using `\AtBeginDocument`, you would have to use `\newgeometry` *after* `\begin{document}` to change the margins. However, if your university provides a template, that does not fit the rules, you should also contact the maintainer of the template.

Comment: @cabohah is it going to ruin the other rules, like "top margin for odd-numbered headers (like 1. INTRODUCTION) must be 5 cm, but for other pages still 2.5 cm" ? Because I have tried similar to your suggestion and it ruined everything else, that's why I want to update it in the above code part.

Comment: @Emr I guess by the last rule they mean the distance between the top of the page and the **Chapter heading** should be 5 cm. That is not a `geometry` parameter, but could be accomplised with `titlesec` or a similar package.

Comment: @Emr Is that template file publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by `geometry` package using with `asymmetric`

Comment: Great. // Can you please Edit your answer and give some more details?